# Why is DocumentFragment ignoring some appended nodes?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to execute this code, but the result I get is `first third`, completely ignoring the middle `<b>second</b>` node. Can someone tell what the problem is?

```js
const html = 'first <b>second</b> third ';
const span = document.createElement('span');
const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
span.innerHTML = html;

for (let node of span.childNodes) {
 frag.appendChild(node);
}

document.body.appendChild(frag);
```

Comment: It's because you're mutating the list of nodes that you're traversing. Every time you remove one from the `span` (by appending it to the fragment), the `.childNodes` is updated and reindexed. Instead do `while(span.firstChild) { frag.appendChild(span.firstChild) }`

Comment: @CrazyTrain Oh how stupid of me, thank you very much. Feel free to add it as an answer.

Comment: FYI, you may want to skip all this work and just use `.insertAdjacentHTML()`, which gives you multiple options for inserting new nodes via HTML markup, so that you can target the exact position of their placement. I updated my answer to show how.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Awesome, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're mutating the list of nodes that you're traversing. Every time you remove one from the `span` (by appending it to the fragment), the `.childNodes` is updated and reindexed.

Since you're transferring all the nodes, use a `while` loop that runs as long as there's at least one child and appends the `.firstChild` to the fragment.

```js
const html = 'first <b>second</b> third ';
const span = document.createElement('span');
const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
span.innerHTML = html;

while (span.firstChild) {
  frag.appendChild(span.firstChild);
}

document.body.appendChild(frag);
```

---

Or just use [`.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead of all this transferring.

```js
const html = 'first <b>second</b> third ';

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
```